# Как замокать для тестирования метод с несколькими лямбдами?

Tags: android, kotlin, mockito

Есть следующий код presenter'a:

```
private fun reserveBadCaseUser(condition: DeviceCondition) {
        showLoad(true)

        deviceInteractor.reserveBadCaseDevice(mCurrentWorker?.id!!, condition,
                {
                    clearCurrentDevice()
                    validateButtonView()
                    showLoad(false)
                },
                {
                    showLoad(false)
                    viewState.showErrorToast(it)
                },
                {
                    showLoad(false)
                    viewState.showErrorToast(it)
                })
    }
```

Метод interactor'a reserveBadCaseDevice выглядит следующим образом:

```
fun reserveBadCaseDevice(workerId: Int,
                             condition: DeviceCondition,
                             result: (Unit) -> Unit,
                             errorText: (String) -> Unit,
                             errorId: (Int) -> Unit) {
        val data = ReservedWorkerData(
                DeviceState.TAKE,
                condition, null,
                workerId)

        val call = apiService.postAsyncReserveDevice(data, prefManager.getPrefToken())
        call.enqueue(object : Callback<Void> {
            override fun onResponse(call: Call<Void>?, response: Response<Void>?) {
                response?.let {
                    if (response.isSuccessful) {
                        result.invoke(Unit)
                    } else {
                        errorText(apiErrorUtil.parse(response).message)
                    }
                }
            }

            override fun onFailure(call: Call<Void>?, t: Throwable?) {
                errorId(apiErrorUtil.parse(t).message)
            }
        })
    }
```

То есть при вызове метода интерактора описываем три лямбды на положительный результат, и ошибку с Int и String значениями в виде лямбд, которые передаем в качестве аргументов метода.

Но при тестировании возникает проблема:

```
@Test
    fun lostClick() {
        val func0 : (Unit) -> Unit = { println("fun0")}
        val func1 : (String) -> Unit = { println("fun1")}
        val func2 : (Int) -> Unit = { println("fun2")}

        whenever(deviceInteractor.reserveBadCaseDevice(
                workerId,
                DeviceCondition.LOST,
                func0,
                func1,
                func2)).then({ func0.invoke(Unit) })

        presenter.lostClick()

        //view reaction
        verify(viewState).showLoad(true)
        verify(viewState).setButtonGiveEnabled(true) //not valid =/
        verify(viewState).setButtonTakeEnabled(false)
        verify(viewState).setButtonCrashEnabled(false)
        verify(viewState).setButtonLostEnabled(false)
        verify(viewState).showLoad(false)
    }
```

Сам метод интерактора вызывается с null параметрами, хотя там точно есть значения workerId и DeviceCondition и они равны именно тем что указаны в методе тестирования. Сама функция func0 которая должна вызываться при положительном результате не вызывается, но ее нужно вызвать для тестирования работы презентера.

Каким образом корректно замокать поведение метода интерактора с лямбдами таким образом что бы отрабатывала определенная лямбда?

Comment: `(Unit) -> Unit` можно заменить на `() -> Unit`.

Comment: @Miha_x64 в следующий раз когда мне потребуется помощь с синтаксисом, я обязательно к вам обращусь, спасибо!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Решение оказалось в использовании метода doAnswer и объекта InvockationOnMock:

```
doAnswer{
            println("invoke")
            val args = it.getArguments()

            (args[2] as (Unit) -> Unit).invoke(Unit)
        }.whenever(deviceInteractor).reserveBadCaseDevice(
                eq(workerId),
                eq(DeviceCondition.LOST),
                any(),
                any(),
                any())
```